# Computing prime ideals in two quotient rings?

Tags: field-theory

I’m trying to go through some examples of computing prime ideals. Could you explain how to compute prime ideals for the following two quotient rings? They are: $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x+y^2)$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x + z^3)$.

Comment: Do you know about the correspondence of prime ideals containing $I$ in $R$ and primes in $R/I$?

Comment: Yes, but I’m having trouble doing this computation.

Comment: Well, as an example, the ideal generated by the image of $z$ in the first ring is prime (why?). It corresponds to the ideal $(x+y^2, z)$ upstairs.

Comment: I’m confused. What is the isomorphism map between the quotient and C[u,v]?

Comment: For example isn’t the ideal $(y^2 +y + x - a, z-b)$ also prime for any complex a or b??

Comment: Why would there be an isomorphism between the quotient and $\mathbb{C}[u,v]$?